# Query not reconizing custom properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have the following query but its not allowing me to select the properties of my custom class for some reason.

This is my class here:

```
public class PersonalDetails
{
    public string LineType { get; set; }
    public string EnquirerTitle { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Employment { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }


}
```

And here I want to use a query to access the data my end goal is to pass this object to a csv selrilizer which I have created to produce a csv file in a custom format.

```
IQueryable<tblapertureNetAppointment> _personadetails;
var personalDetails = from _appointments in  _dal.apertureNetEntities.tblapertureNetAppointments
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new PersonalDetails { x.LineType its not allowing me to find line type})
.ToList();
```

Comment: You are not mixing up between _persondetails and personalDetails, which might be of different types, right ?

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is or how to reproduce it.  Please see [MCVE].

Comment: Your second code block appears to have an invalid mix of comprehension expression and LINQ extension methods: please use one or the other.

Comment: ` x.LineType` is from table right??

Comment: x line type is from the public class

Comment: "for some reason" there is no evidence of this in your question.  Oddly enough, that evidence is what people need to help you.  You should [edit] and fix.

Comment: Will are u not reading the question what is this line  { x.LineType its not allowing me to find line type})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way -

```
var personalDetails = (from _appointments in  _dal.apertureNetEntities.tblapertureNetAppointments.AsEnumerable()
                       select new PersonalDetails {

                         LineType = _appointments.LineType,
                         EnquirerTitle = _appointments.EnquirerTitle,
                         ForeName = _appointments.ForeName,
                         Surname = _appointments.Surname,
                         // .......
                       }).ToList();
```

**Update**

Using LinqToCsv you can write csv file from your linq object. LinqToCsv is available as nuget package.

From Package Manager Console -

```
 Install-Package LinqToCsv
```

Now you can write your linq object to csv file this way -

```
CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = '\t', // tab delimited
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true, 
    FileCultureName = "nl-NL" // use formats used in The Netherlands
};

CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

string fileName = String.Format(@"{0}products2.csv", Server.MapPath("/csvFiles")); 
cc.Write(personalDetails,fileName,outputFileDescription);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support always nice we newbies help newbies

Comment: Is linq to csv worth looking at for this task I need to conver that custom class then into csv file